# How do I capture the output of a pry shell command?

Tags: ruby, shell, pry

I'm using pry and I want to capture, and work with output of a shell command.

For example, If I run

```
pry(main)> .ls
```

I want to get the list of files into an array that I can work with in Ruby.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty old question but I'll answer it anyways. There are two primary methods of getting data out of pry commands. The first is if the command sets the `keep_retval` option to true, which the shell command does not. The second, is to use the virtual pipe. In your example this can be done as:

```
fizz = []
.ls | {|listing| fizz = listing.split("\n")} # can also be written as
.ls do |listing|
  fizz = listing.split("\n")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume it's some kind of pry's magic ;-)

After quick look at what's happening (I didn't look at pry's source), you might want to use this:

```
`ls`.split("\n")
```

or

```
Dir['./*']
```

What's good about this solution is that it will work outside of `pry`